# what's difference between Ctrl+B and Ctrl+Alt+F7 in intellij IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

<kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> :Go to declaration,Navigate directly to an element's declaration from any usage.
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>:Show usages,Show usages of a symbol at the caret.

I usually use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to find usages,but I come across some problems:
for example,when I use ctrl+B on Thread's field  private Runnable target; it tell me 'No usages found in Project Files  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> again to search in Project and **Libraries**' and indeed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> can find those usage.
But in my own class A's field ,use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> can find all the usage in A.
In my opinion,<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> can show usages in some situation,so what's the relationship between them?

As Tom pointed,except <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> cann't find usages in Libraries,are they interchageable?

BTW, I use injtellij idea 2016.1.3 with default keymap.

Comment: Ctrl+B *"No usages found in **Project Files**"* ... Ctrl+Alt+F7 *"search in **Project and Libraries**"*, so what was the question again?

Comment: @Tom do you mean they can be used interchangeable except involve **Libraries**?

Comment: Ctrl+B still requires to navigate to the declaration first, so it is up to you if you want to do that every time, when you like to search for the usage.

Comment: @Tom ,if I use on the declaration directly, they are the same(except Libraries)?